# How To Use Generated Matlab Code in Android?

Tags: android, matlab, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have generated MATLAB code than contains a lot of C codes and C/C++ headers.I don't know how to use this code with NDK in Android.

1-Should I change c codes for use in Android?

2-How to use this codes in Android Project?

3-Is there any tutorial or book to use generated code in Android Project?

Answer (score 1):

The android can interact with c/c++ code using [JNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface). Here are some links which may help you understand the Interaction between Native Code and Android Java Language.

[Using C and C++ Code in an Android App with the NDK](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-c-and-c-code-in-an-android-app-with-the-ndk)

[Add native code to android](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code)

and so on...